# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist when trying to use constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, constraints

I have been trying to create a table using constraints because that is what our professor wants ous to do. However, when I do so I get a ton of errors when before I had none. My code looks like the following:

```
DROP TABLE movie CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE movie(
movie_id NUMBER(5),
title VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL,
released_by NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
released_on DATE NOT NULL
constraint movie_pk primary key (movie_id));

INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES ('1', 'Edge of Tomorrow', 'Lieutenant Colonel Bill Cage is a skilled tactician who has honed his abilities through his experiences as a soldier. However, there is still much he can learn, and soon he is going to get his chance.', '1', '07-OCT-2014');

INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('2', 'Captain America: Winter Soldier', 'Steve Rogers is finding it difficult to adjust to living life in the contemporary world. He is working for S.H.I.E.L.D. and begins to suspect a mystery is brewing there.', '2', '09-SEP-2014');

INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('3', 'Fed Up', 'America’s problem with obesity is caused by our inactivity. Or is it? Katie Couric and Stephanie Soechtig tempt us to restructure our beliefs about the American diet, through this thought-provoking expose.', '3', '09-SEP-2014');

INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('4', 'Godzilla', 'The legendary tale of Godzilla comes roaring back to life. This time, its the modern era, and Godzilla is a giant lizard who has been made fearsome through the interference of radiation.', '1', '16-SEP-2014');

INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('5', 'Neighbors', 'New parents Mac and Kelly settle into domesticity in a quiet neighborhood. The tranquility they have been afforded ceases to exist when a fraternity moves into the house next door.', '2', '14-SEP-2014');

COMMIT;
```

The out put from me running this code in Oracle is as follows:

```
SQL> @test.sql
DROP TABLE movie CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


constraint movie_pk primary key (movie_id))
                                *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES ('1', 'Edge of Tomorrow', 'Lieutenant Colonel Bill Cage is a skilled tactician who has honed his abilities through his experiences as a soldier. However, there is still much he can learn, and soon he is going to get his chance.', '1', '07-OCT-2014')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('2', 'Captain America: Winter Soldier', 'Steve Rogers is finding it difficult to adjust to living life in the contemporary world. He is working for S.H.I.E.L.D. and begins to suspect a mystery is brewing there.', '2', '09-SEP-2014')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('3', 'Fed Up', 'Americas problem with obesity is caused by our inactivity. Or is it? Katie Couric and Stephanie Soechtig tempt us to restructure our beliefs about the American diet, through this thought-provoking expose.', '3', '09-SEP-2014')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('4', 'Godzilla', 'The legendary tale of Godzilla comes roaring back to life. This time, its the modern era, and Godzilla is a giant lizard who has been made fearsome through the interference of radiation.', '1', '16-SEP-2014')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, title, description, released_by, released_on)VALUES('5', 'Neighbors', 'New parents Mac and Kelly settle into domesticity in a quiet neighborhood. The tranquility they have been afforded ceases to exist when a fraternity moves into the house next door.', '2', '14-SEP-2014')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



Commit complete.
```

As you can see there are multiple errors within this code just from me adding constraints. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing a comma:

```
released_on DATE NOT NULL,
                         ^ 
constraint movie_pk primary key (movie_id));
```

Comment: It is always something simple. Thank you